# Drawing large graph with graphviz

Tags: graph, graphviz, draw

I have here generated a large *.dot* file of my facebook friends' graph with [fb-map](http://github.com/trampj/fb-map). It has 287 nodes and almost 2000 edges. I'm using `dot` and `neato` to generate a *.png* image, using the `overlap="orthoyx"` paramethers, but it doesn't give a nice effect. Too many overlapped edges.

Do you know any set of options to manage such huge graphs and draw them in an eye-readable way with Graphviz?

Comment: Did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238724/visualizing-undirected-graph-thats-too-large-for-graphviz yet ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [igraph](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/) library layout algorithms seem to cope much better with very large graphs than dot does. It even includes an implementation of Kamada-Kawai and Fruchterman-Reingold layout algorithms.

There are up-to-date [python bindings](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/download.html) available, not to mention [nice documentation](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/python/index.html) and [tutorials](http://www.cs.rhul.ac.uk/home/tamas/development/igraph/tutorial/tutorial.html).