# Collapsing graph by clusters in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I want to collapse a graph into its respective communities/clusters.  Let me illustrate this with the following toy example:

```
set.seed(123)

#toy graph
g <- barabasi.game(10) %>%
  as.undirected()

#identify communities 
c_g <- fastgreedy.community(g)
```

There are three communities, as seen in the following graph.

[image]

I want to reduce the collapse the vertices so that vertices in the resulting graph correspond to the membership of the previous vertices.  See the graph.

[image]

I'm new to the `igraph` package and I'm not familiar with the best way of dealing with `igraph` objects.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try `contract`:

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(123)
g <- barabasi.game(10) %>% as.undirected()
c_g <- fastgreedy.community(g) 
V(g)$name <- letters[1:vcount(g)]

g2 <- contract(g, membership(c_g), vertex.attr.comb=toString)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(g, vertex.color=membership(c_g))
plot(simplify(g2), vertex.color=1:vcount(g2))
```

[image]