# Visualizing extra large (100 million nodes) graphs

Tags: c++, graph, visualization

I have a sparse extra large directed graph with hundreds of millions of nodes, but the nodes have a max out degree and max in degree of 4 (most have out degree of 2 in fact). So it's quite sparse. I know that graphviz is a good choice but it only offers visualising without downsample which is obviously not a choice if the number of nodes is more than a hundred million.

Are there tools, preferably C/C++ based (because performance is of importance of course) that offer such visualisations?

I'm aware of similar questions asked on SO, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667166/visualize-big-graphs) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238724/visualizing-undirected-graph-thats-too-large-for-graphviz) but to me they sound like a different problem, both in terms of scale of the graph, its topology, and the technology.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238724/visualizing-undirected-graph-thats-too-large-for-graphviz#comment102544_238724